# jQuery Ajax post can't send data

Tags: jquery

I have the HTML form, the data sending to the local PHPscript, and to the remote php by jQuery. The problem is I can't send data to my remote PHP, for this I have tried to use jQuery Ajax.

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='e.js'></script>
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" id="registration" action="function.php">  
  Name: <input type="text" id="nameq" name="name" value="">
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" id="website" name="website" value="">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="other">Other  
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>
  <button id="button" type="submit" form="registration">Submit</button>
</form>
</html>
```

the e.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var cln = $("#nameq").val();
        $.post("https://test/index.php", {"cln": cln});
    });
});
```

1. If `$("#button").click(function()`
   Mozilla Firefox 68 shows "NS_BINDING_ABORTED", Chrome 76 can't send
2. If `$("#button").submit(function()`
   Mozilla Firefox shows nothing, can't send, Chrome can't send
3. There is solution `$.ajaxSetup({async: false})` both browsers work properly but I don't want to use it

What am I doing wrong, is there solution by changing only e.js? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

What is happening in your case is the `<button type="submit">` is submitting the form before your click event is getting called. You will need to use [jQuery submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on that get's triggered whenever the form is submitted

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#registration").submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var cln = $("#nameq").val();
        $.post(url, {"cln": cln});
    });
});
```

Here, the key is the method call `event.preventDefault()`.

Quoting from the docs

> jQuery's submit event fires prior to the actual submission so we can
>   cancel the submit event by this call on the event object.

Comment: Isn't it, in that case, complete obsolete to use a from? If he removes the form he will not get a submit and the click will work?

Comment: Yeah, that also makes sense.

Comment: I can only receive data in my remote php script, but not in my local php

Comment: @alex: Sorry, I did not understand what you meant by local PHP and remote PHP. Can you elaborate?

Comment: local php is http://localhost/function.php where data send by form with traditional submit (<form method="post"action="function.php"...> and <button id="button" type="submit"...>). Remote php is http://remote-server/function2.php where I would like to send data by jQuery ajax post. So when user type data on my form and click Submit, the data should send to my local and remote php file 'simultaneously'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my unclear question, but I think there is a misunderstanding. My goal is I would like to receive data in my local php script - function.php and in my remote php - https://test/index.php. Right now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registration").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var cln = $("#nameq").val();
        $.post("https://test/index.php", {"cln": cln});
    });
});
```

I can receive data in my remote php script, but then the data is not sent to the local php - function.php. With $.ajaxSetup({async: false}):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var cln = $("#nameq").val();
        $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
        $.post("https://test/index.php", {"cln": cln});
    });
});
```

there is delay (my site is waiting for answer from remote php script) and I don't like it. I want to do it simultaneously send data to the local and remote php script